# Used a debit card to book on booking.com for a hotel for six months that I thought had free cancellations

Tags: booking.com

I just used my credit card to book a hotel for six months booking.com that I thought had free cancellation. I immediately found it that each month I booked had like 3K in cancellation costs, I cancelled immediately but the website said I cancelled for "3k" for each month. As this total adds up to more than 18k, I'm freaking out right now. Am I really liable for this much money in cancellation costs? My bank account has nowhere near that amount of money, and I was not charged yet.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Did you look at your booking and read the rules and terms? What do they say?

Comment: 3K what? Euros, US dollars, ruppees?

Comment: Your question title says debit, but the question I'll says credit card. To avoid any confusion, which is correct?